# Full list of all packages available through pip install command?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Where can I find a complete list of all the packages/libraries that can be installed using `pip`? (note: I don't mean package that I *have already* installed, I mean all possible packages available using `pip`). Also note: [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) would be the equivalent for the R programming language

Comment: There are thousands of them. Maybe millions. Are you sure you want to list them all? Instead of googling "package to do something".

Comment: @sanyash is there a central repository? Or is anyone completely free to add packages as they please? In the R language, all packages are vetted by volunteers before they're available on 'the' central repository (CRAN), of course there are many more on github and elsewhere too, I'm just after the 'official' ones.

Comment: https://pypi.org/

Comment: pip draws from PyPI. it says 200,000 packages currently

Comment: Why do you need a complete list?

Comment: @PeterWood mostly curiosity, but also to learn of new/different packages, and to try to get an idea of whether I'm using the right packages (or if I've strayed far off the beaten track - not always a bad thing, but not always recommended either). But I'd need downloads/usage stats for the latter..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+list+available+packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a full list here:

https://pypi.org/simple/

This will take a while to load though. As for `pip` itself, there is `pip search <term>`, but no full listing of packages available from a repository.

Also see [pip documentation here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/).

As came up in comments on the question:

> is there a central repository? Or is anyone completely free to add
>   packages as they please?

[Finding packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages) in the `pip` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For all python packages which can be installed with the `pip install <package>` command, I would suggest you check this link out https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python

Also for all R packages which can also be installed with the `pip install <package>`, you could also visit this [https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+R](https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Programming%20Language%20%3A%3A%20R) link for the list